# SwipeRefreshLayout in Kivy

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I'm developing an App in Kivy technology and I want to display a pull to refresh behaviour. The most I've done is a scroll view and control if the scroll_y coordinate to refresh but this has the disadvantage of only working if there is scroll and doesn't work if there isn't.

```
<TrytonTree>
app: app
container: container
do_scroll_x: False
on_scroll_y: root.init_pull(self.scroll_y)
on_scroll_stop: root.pull(self.scroll_y)
MDList:
    id: container
...
class TrytonTree(ScrollView, TrytonTreeMixin):

def pull(self, scroll_y):
    if scroll_y >= 2:
        self.app.refresh_screen([self.get_model_name()])
        Clock.schedule_once(self.app.disable_spinner, 2)

def init_pull(self, scroll_y):
    if scroll_y >= 2:
        self.app.enable_spinner()
```

So my question is if there is a way of controlling the swipe gesture so I can call the refresh function or something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on motion events directly for this kind of stuff:

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html

I think you could do something like:

```
on_touch_move(self, touch):
    self.refresh()
```

Comment: It's a good solution, the only problem is that I'd have to detect the swipe move with coordinates and the motion "move up" I suppose but it could work out. Thank you.